# Swift function Parameter: Name and Object type

Tags: swift, parameters, named-parameters

I have a question regarding the syntax of function parameters. Take this function for example:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
    //code goes here    
}
```

In the function definition, each parameter has a variable name and a colon followed by an object type.

**Question**

In above function why are there two names? `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and `indexPath`.

Should I be using the `indexPath` variable?

What concept is involved here?

Comment: @robmayoff  thank you! `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is the external parameter name while `indexPath` is the internal parameter name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cellForRowAtIndexPath` is a *named* (or external) parameter for the actual `indexPath` parameter also known as the internal parameter. The *named* parameter is what you use when *calling* the function. Put simply, you have the ability to name a parameter something different than the name of your actual input variable name.

**A simplified example**

In the following example I've made a simple object with a *named* parameter of `germanShepherd`:

```
func getDog(barks: Bool, germanShepherd dog: String) {}
```

Then when I call the function I use:

```
getDog(true, germanShepherd: myValue)
```

In my simple example the *named* parameter can help clear up the ambiguity of the "dog" parameter, just as `cellForRowAtIndexPath` helps to clear up the ambiguity of the `indexPath` parameter.

**Removing the named parameter**

You also have the option to remove the named parameter by utilizing an underscore in place of the named parameter like so:

```
func getDog(barks: Bool, _ dog: String) {}

getDog(true, "yes")
```

Of course this is all subject to change in **Swift 3**!

### [swift evolution](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.swift.evolution/4059)

Answer (score 2):

In objective-c (this concept was also implemented in swift) there are these things called "named" parameters that assist you in letting you know as to what type of information you need to supply the function for it to do its job. `indexPath` is the actual variable you'll use within your function, while `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is nothing more than a named parameter telling you what goes here. I hope that helps!